# How do I preserve existing files when installing an MSDeploy package?

Tags: iis, msdeploy

I need to preserve some files, generated by my site.

Is it possible to make MSDeploy not delete any files, and overwrite existing files only when the package contains a newer version of a file?

Comment: How is it supposed to know when a file in the package is "newer"? If the files are different they will be updated. Do you want to simply skip a known folder(s) or file(s)?

Comment: @Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi, it's supposed to compare file dates. But writing only files that weren't existing before can be ok too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add this code into my csproj file, it prevents any deletions and updates in App_Data folder on deploy:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OnBeforePackageUsingManifest>AddSkipRules</OnBeforePackageUsingManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="AddSkipRules">
    <ItemGroup>
      <MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipDeleteAppData">
        <SkipAction>Delete</SkipAction>
        <ObjectName>filePath</ObjectName>
        <AbsolutePath>$(_Escaped_PackageTempDir)\\App_Data\\.*</AbsolutePath>
        <XPath>
        </XPath>
      </MsDeploySkipRules>
      <MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipDeleteAppData">
        <SkipAction>Delete</SkipAction>
        <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
        <AbsolutePath>$(_Escaped_PackageTempDir)\\App_Data\\.*</AbsolutePath>
        <XPath>
        </XPath>
      </MsDeploySkipRules>
      <MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipUpdateAppData">
        <SkipAction>Update</SkipAction>
        <ObjectName>filePath</ObjectName>
        <AbsolutePath>$(_Escaped_PackageTempDir)\\App_Data\\.*</AbsolutePath>
        <XPath>
        </XPath>
      </MsDeploySkipRules>
      <MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipUpdateAppData">
        <SkipAction>Update</SkipAction>
        <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
        <AbsolutePath>$(_Escaped_PackageTempDir)\\App_Data\\.*</AbsolutePath>
        <XPath>
        </XPath>
      </MsDeploySkipRules>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Comment: I am getting an error that I've seen other people get without a resolution. 

Unrecognized skip directive 'skipaction'. Must be one of the following: "objectName," "keyAttribute," "absolutePath," "xPath," "attributes.<name>."

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

*-enableRule:SkipNewerFilesRule* will skip updates to files that have a more recent write time. *-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule* will block deletion of files on the destination computer, but this rule only works with the *contentPath*, *dirPath*, and *filePath* providers. I have used the skipRule *-skip:skipAction=Delete,objectName=dirPath,absolutePath=.** to simulate the *DoNotDeleteRule*. It has worked well for me so far.