# Deploying Impacted Files using MSDeploy

Tags: .net, webdeploy, msdeploy

We are trying to use MSDeploy to deploy our site to IIS. Everything is fine but there is a hitch and we are unable to solve that issue.

As a part of our development scenario, we don't want to deploy all files of a build. We want to deploy only impacted files (i.e) selective files. [useChecksum doesn't seem to be an option because we don't want all modified files to be deployed].

We saw potential in MSDeploy to help automate such scenarios but we are failing as it is syncing impacted files in the source with the destination. The end result is, files except impacted files are deleted in destination (as it is a sync operation).

Ideally the selective files should replace the files in the destination and other ones mustn't be deleted.

The command we followed is:

```
msdeploy.exe -source:iisApp=some/path/to/files -allowUntrusted:true -dest:iisApp=esapi,computerName="https://someName:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=esapi",userName='admin',password='admin@123',auth='Basic' -verb:sync
```

How can we achieve such scenario?

Need Help!

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I preserve existing files when installing an MSDeploy package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655915/how-do-i-preserve-existing-files-when-installing-an-msdeploy-package)

Comment: @SamAxe haha...but our situation is like that. It looks like it works but it really doesn’t work.

Comment: @SamAxe I had a look at the link you had provided. So according to our situation, we must be using content path (source: path to the impact files and dest: site name) along with prevent delete option. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: as far as I can tell, yes.

Comment: @SamAxe It has worked man!!! Thank you very much for the help :)